# Asus DUAL RX580 O8G troubles with vbios

Tags: mining

Today I got a problem with my 2 cards and I don't know what to do. I have 2 Asus DUAL-RX580-O8G graphic cards. The first one mined ehtereum at 17-18 mh/s, second did it at 16-17 mh/s. I decided to flash bios of these two cards to get to 29 mh/s on both.

I used PolarisBiosEditor and AtiWinFlash. I've done back up of original vbios of only first card because I thought that if both cards were the same model then they should have same bios. Then I patched bios for the first card with bios downloaded from the internet which was already setted for Asus DUAL-RX580-O8G to go on 29 mh/s. But Claymore crashed with this bios so I decided to go back to restore back up I made before. And here thing went quite strange. After I restored old bios for the first card both cards started to mine at 3.5 mh/s. I thought that I did something wrong and decided to restore again. But nothing changed.

Then I thought that probably I made something wrong during back up so I decided to get bios of the second card. But I found out that second card had Hylix as a memory manufacturer and the first one had Samsung. Here I have understood that've done something very wrong. I've tried to mine separately on this cards but they still mined at 3.5 mh/s. I reinstalled driver but it didn't help.

Then I googled for original vbios for Asus DUAL-RX580-O8G and found one for Samsung memory manufacturer. I installed it on both cards (on the second with Hylix memory too) and then they started to mine at 18.5 mh/s each. But this driver is different from that I've back up before all this happend. It has different GPU and Power paramenters.

So can you help me to deal with these questions:
1. Is it OK that I installed bios for Samsung memory on the card that originally had Hylix memory?

2. Is it normal that two cards of the same model could have different memory manufacturers?
3. What does GPU table parameters mean? And why such small difference in this table affects so much card performance?
4. And also why original vbios I made gives such a small hashrate after being reinstalled?

[This is the link to all 3 versions of bios I used.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1S1pAUsbLuurz30QCQHqF-3ShgbLXr32Y)

Any help appriciated! Thanks!

Comment: Hi there. I think you might have more luck on https://www.reddit.com/r/EtherMining/.

Answer (score 0):

So first of all, AMD cards need a setting to be switched in the AMD driver. If you go into the AMD Settings (Radeon Settings) program and click 'Gaming' then 'Global Settings' then change the GPU Workload from Gaming to Compute FOR EACH CARD. It will make you restart the program for each card.

See what results you get after that.
Then I would try changing the VBIOS and memory strap timings etc.